# JSON.NET Deserializing Client Side

Tags: c#, javascript, json, knockout.js, json.net

In C# I do this from a controller:

```
public ActionResult GetCompanies()
{
    var vm = new CompanyViewModel { jsonData = JsonConvert.Serialize(_repository.All<Company>()) };

    return View(vm);
}
```

ViewModel looks like this:

```
public CompanyViewModel
{
    public string jsonData {get;set}
}
```

On the client side:

```
@model MyWebApp.ViewModels.CompanyViewModel

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
<script type="text/javascript">
   var serverData = <!-- Many Things To Do Here -->
</script>
```

In the part `<!-- Many Things To Do Here -->` there a few things you can do to put the server data into a JavaScript Object.

What is the best way to do this, because I have had problems with `JSON.parse` to do with some characters JSON.NET serializes.

Is just putting the plain data in there okay (it works): `var serverData = @Html.Raw(@Model.jsonData)`

What other things should/can be done here?

Comment: Why send a string if you are trying to parse it into JSON on the client. You are already sending JSON back to the client, just make jsonData a real .NET object on the server that can be serialized to the client.

Comment: I'm asking what is acceptable to serialize a C# object into a set of JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a model just to hold a JSON string, just pass the plain .NET object to your view, and serialize it to JSON there:

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetCompanies()
{
    return View(_repository.All<Comapny>());
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<script>
    var companies = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
</script>
```

If you want/need a strongly typed model in your view, you should change your `CompanyViewModel` to this:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public IList<Company> Companies {get; set;}
    //Or whatever sort of collection your repository returns
}
```

And in your controller

```
public ActionResult GetCompanies()
{
    var vm = new CompanyViewModel { Companies = _repository.All<Company>() };
    return View(vm);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model MyWebApp.ViewModels.CompanyViewModel
<script>
    var companies = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Companies));
</script>
```

Comment: So you are saying that you can just set a variable to converted JSON then?